Configuration not loaded from environment variables
I have some values for the application configuration in appsettings.json file and some values in environment variables. I expect the configuration key values to be populated with the values from the environment variable, but it is just empty. Can you please help me?
I am creating the builder as below.
builder.Configuration.AddEnvironmentVariables(prefix:"MyApp_");
builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json",optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);

I am accessing the configuration as below.
MyAppOptions options = new(); 
config.GetSection(MyAppOptions.SectionName).Bind(options); 

Appsettings.json has the below config. I am having the actual clientSecret key value in environment variable and leaving it empty in appsettings.json.
{
  "myAppOptions": {
    "serverUrl": "https://serverurl.net",
    "clientId": "8132498b-a8d1-47bc-b08a-0ba9d85e3035",
    "clientSecret": ""
  }
}

Environment variable key value is set like below.
MyApp_MyAppOptions_ClientSecret=dummy-value


Configuration properties are separated by colons (:), but the environment variable configuration provider also supports double underscores (__) because not all environments allow colons in environment variables names. As such, it is recommended to always use double underscores.
That means you're missing an additional underscore in between MyAppOptions and ClientSecret:
MyApp_MyAppOptions__ClientSecret=dummy-value

The single underscore after MyApp is part of your prefix, so you shouldn't double it up.
For more information, see the documentation on the topic.
The order in which the configuration providers are added also matters.

Configuration providers that are added later have higher priority and
override previous key settings.

In this case the environment variables configuration settings will be overridden by the settings from appsettings.json, since appsettings.json is added after environment variables configuration provider. If you want the environment variable value for ClientSecret to override the empty string value from appsettings.json, change the order as below.
builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json",optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);
builder.Configuration.AddEnvironmentVariables(prefix:"MyApp_");

